# Tensor product of universe Hilbert space and black hole Hilbert space equals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, hilbert-space, information, unitarity

I'm a newbie struggling to parse concepts important in black hole, 
holographic principle and related issues.  My query comes from 
Thomas Thiemann’s Modern Canonical Quantum Gen. Relativity,
which states about black holes:

> “…as long as the black hole has not completely evaporated the
>   total system is described by a tensor product of Hilbert spaces for the
>   inside and the outside of the black hole…” (pg. 100)…

Sooooo:

I naively assume a tensor product $U (x) BH = W$, where $U$ is the universe
external to a black hole and BH is the interior region of the black hole.
Pretending that one could actually formulate the Hilbert space for the
universe, ie: with as yet unspecified details… what is the most one can
say about W ?  And ||W||^.5 ?  I’m especially motivated here by the
literature exploring the possibility that black holes may mediate creation
of baby universes (see work by Vafa, Ooguri, Aganagik and others).